# Double list comprehension NameError

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
print [a for a in range(1,b) for b in range (1,10)]
```

This gives me a NameError because b is not defined.

I believe somewhere in Python's awesomeness there must be a way to do this though.

To give a bit more detail about what it is i'm trying to do, i have a function like:

```
def MyFunction(condition):
    data = Query % condition
    return data
```

And i want a to make a list of all elements when several different conditions are run i.e.

```
AllData = [d for d in MyFunction(condition) for condition in conditions]
```

Comment: You have your `for` loops inverted. `b` is not defined because the `for a in range(1, b)` loop is executed **first**.

Comment: I thought this might be the case but i can't visualise how to do it the other way round

Comment: List comprehension `for` loops are ordered the same way you'd nest them. You'd use `for b in range(1, 10)` as the *outer* loop, so put that first, after which follows the inner loop, here `for a in range(1, b)`: `[a for b in range(1, b) for b in range (1,10)]`. Or your other loop: `[d for condition in conditions for d in MyFunction(condition)]`